ggplot2 histogram with ratios and facet_wrap
I am having issues with ggplot2 geom_histogram when plotting frequencies and using facet_wrap at the same time:
#
myTestDF<- data.frame(
  Sample = as.vector(replicate(n = 6, expr = c('s1', 's2', 's3'))),
  var2 = c(
    replicate(n = 9, expr = 't1'),
    replicate(n = 9, expr = 't2')),
  Val1 = c(
    replicate(n = 3, expr = c(2,20,40)),
    replicate(n = 3, expr = c(0.2,0.4,0.6))),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myTestDF<- rbind(myTestDF, data.frame(Sample = 's2', var2 = 't1', Val1 = 70,
                                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) ##afterthought :)
myTestDF$var3<- paste(myTestDF$Sample, myTestDF$var2, sep = '_')

###Now, this works:

ggplot(
  data = myTestDF[myTestDF$Sample=='s2',],
  aes(x = Val1, fill = var2)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(c(
      count[group==1]/sum(count[group==1]),
      count[group==2]/sum(count[group==2])))),
    position = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(title = 'testHist',
       x = "Val1", y = "Frequency") +
  theme_minimal() 

#

However, I can't figure a way to make it work with facet_wrap by 'Sample'. The frequencies get all messed up, and after experimenting and reading around, I can't find a way to do it. Of course I can do a for loop , but I would like to understand if it can be done with facet_wrap or other ggplot2 function. Looking forward to your feedback.

Can you be more clear on what the desired output is? What should the plot look like? What do you want the bars to represent? The data looks so discrete, are you sure you need a histogram and not a bar chart?

Thank you, MrFlick, I will be more clear on the desired output next time. Regarding the data, these are just test numbers so I can check by eye if the result is correct.

The issue is that you do not account for the panels when computing the relative frequencies separately for each group, i.e. when you use facet_wrap the data is ordered first by PANEL and second by group. Instead I would suggest to use e.g. ave() to compute the relative frequencies. In the code below I also added the PANEL as a second grouping variable.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  myTestDF, aes(x = Val1, fill = var2)
) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(
      ave(count, group, PANEL, FUN = \(x) x / sum(x))
    )),
    position = "identity", alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "testHist",
    x = "Val1", y = "Frequency"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~Sample)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.



That is great, thank you for the answer and for the explanation.. Did not know the 'ave' function, I am reading about it right now. I thought I had a decent understanding of ggplot2 by now, there is no end to learning
